# Have jQuery calculate a div height, minus a specific em value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have layout build using ems. jQuery be default uses pixels. I would like to:

- Insert an em value where currently 450 pixels are being subtracted.

If it helps I did find a [plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/arasbm/jQuery-Pixel-Em-Converter/master/pxem.jQuery.js) from Filament Group but am unsure how to use the plugin in the function I am using. I am open to all suggestions!

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height() - 450){
        $('#call').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('#call').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

I prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/utjrkry8/2/), any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would need to convert `em` to `px`, but most posts say that it's impossible. I could suggest creating a hidden div of width 1em, get it's width (in pixels) with javascript and use that rate to convert em to px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create hidden div of width 1em with the same font-size as in your header.
- Get it's width `var ww = $("#hidden_div").width();`
- Use this rate to convert em to px. `var the_pixels = em_wanted * ww;`
- Use that much pixels - `$('#header').height() - the_pixels`

Answer (score 0):

Using the plugin from Filament Group as linked in your first post:

```
if (distanceFromTop >= $('#header').height() - $(8).toPx()){
```

This subtracts the px value of 8em from `#header` height .

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, I tried using it but it doesn't work in the setup I am using. [jsfiddle (2)](https://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/utjrkry8/3/)  versus [jsfiddle (1)](https://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/utjrkry8/2/)

Comment: @Scopestyle You need the `.toPx()` in [jsfiddle (2)](https://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/utjrkry8/3/), you only have `.toEm()`